# What is the correct way to pass a initializer list of strings as a pointer to another function in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an initializer vector as a pointer to function `check()` as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void check(vector<std::string>* vecptr) {
    cout << "size of vecptr: " << vecptr->size() << endl;
}

int main() {
    check({"hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"});
    return 0;
}
```

But above code returns `error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*`.

How to pass such an hard coded initializer list as a pointer?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? Whats the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why is the parameter a pointer?

Comment: Why a pointer? The code would work fine if you just removed the `*` and replaced `->` by `.`. (Although you would typically use `std::initializer_list` instead of `std::vector` in such a situation.)

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Why would you pass a pointer to an initializer list to a function expecting a pointer to a vector? Why do you want to use pointers instead of references? _"What is the correct way to pass a initializer list of strings as a pointer to another function in C++?"_ There is no correct way to do this.

Comment: Don't use pointers (when you don't have to), `void check(const std::vector<std::string>& strings)`. Or for constant strings consider using string_view.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to use the initializer list:
[initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

About your code here is a working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void check(const std::vector<std::string>* vecptr) {
    std::cout << "size of vecptr: " << vecptr->size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec{"hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"};
    check(&vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of vecptr: 5
```

If you look on your declaration which is `const std::vector<std::string>* vecptr` you can't pass directly `check({"hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"});` because you need to pass the vector by reference. So if you want to use like in your example `check({"hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"});`.

Change:

```
void check(const std::vector<std::string>* vecptr)
```

To:

```
void check(const std::vector<std::string>& vecptr)
```

Here is a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void check(const std::vector<std::string>& vecptr) {
    std::cout << "size of vecptr: " << vecptr.size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    check({"hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"});
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of vecptr: 5
```